# Why is my MongoDB aggregation query so slow

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I have several IDs (usually 2 or 3) of users whom I need to fetch from the database. Thing is, I also need to know the distance from a certain point. Problem is, my collection has 1,000,000 documents (users) in it, and it takes upwards of 30 seconds to fetch the users.

Why is this happening? When I just use the `$in` operator for the `_id` it works fine and returns everything in under 200ms, and when I just use the `$geoNear` operator it also works fine, but when I use the 2 together everything slows down insanely. What do I do? Again, all I need is a few users with the IDs from the `userIds` array and their distance from a certain point (`user.location`).

EDIT: Also wanted to mention that when i use `$nin` instead of `$in` the query also performs pefrectly. Only `$in` is causing the problem when combined with `$geoNear`

```
const user = await User.findById('logged in users id');
const userIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];

[
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: user.location,
            distanceField: 'distance',
            query: {
                _id: { $in: userIds }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any indexes on the ID or the geospatial fields?

Comment: If you run `db.coll.explain().aggregate(yourPipeline)` you'll probably find it's not using the `_id` index (only the 2dIndex). And you can't run a match because it has to be the first stage. You can only try to workaround with some other operator. Also, I suspect if you add `{$project:{geolocationField:1}}` it will run quicker, but you should test, and idk how useless this will become.

Comment: @AliDowair the query won't run without geospatial index

Comment: The location does indeed have a 2dsphere index. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around: i just query by the ID field, and later I use a library to determine the distance of the returned docs from the central point.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing your data could be a solution to your problem. without indexing mongodb has to scan through all documents.

Comment: I have an index for both the ID and the location field. That's why I was confused, considering both are indexed, why does it take so long? In any case I found a work-around as stated in my answer. Thanks for the input anyway